# Add button to dynamic module backend list sitefinity

Tags: sitefinity

I created export button based on [this article](https://knowledgebase.progress.com/articles/Article/Add-button-to-dynamic-module-backend-page). Button button not showing in backend list screen.
This is [Backend page](https://i.stack.imgur.com/dvaFV.png) and this is [Backend list (preview mode)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/or237.png)

Can anyone help me explain why it happened and how can I to fix it.

Comment: Try switching to the old UI and see if the button appears

Comment: Thanks. I switched to old UI and the button appeared. Is there any way for the button appear on new interface?

Comment: Cool, for the new UI you probably need to extend the AdminApp - see here: https://github.com/Sitefinity/sitefinity-admin-app-extensions